# Worker for Gearman getting Segmentation Fault

Tags: php, ubuntu, gearman

I am getting error when run my worker:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I'm getting a segmentation fault when trying to run worker for  Gearman Client via the command line.

This message worker getting after few correct response.

My worker code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use ClickHouseDB\Client;
use ClickHouseDB\Quote\FormatLine;

$config = [
    'host' => '',
    'port' => 0,
    'username' => '',
    'password' => ''
];
$db = new Client($config);
$db->database('mydb');  

$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer('127.0.0.1', '4730');
$worker->addFunction("send_to_clickhouse", "processing", $db);


while (1)
{
  $worker->work();
  if ($worker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS){
      echo "return_code: " . $gmworker->returnCode() . "\n";
      break;
  }
}

function processing($job, $db)
{
    $message =  $job->workload();
    $data = json_decode($message, true);
    $statement = $db->insert($data['table_name'], [array_values($data['columns'])], array_keys($data['columns']));
    $statement->error();
    echo $data['table_name']."\n";
}
?>
```

Run worker:

`php worker.php`

Worker output:

```
table1
table2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am using `smi2/phpclickhouse` extension to send data to database

PHP version:

```
PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2019 17:05:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Command `dmesg` return:

```
...
[168928.288846] traps: php[29065] general protection ip:5558a2d01be0 sp:7ffc92fc4cf0 error:0 in php7.2[5558a2a87000+419000]
[168963.415479] traps: php[29071] general protection ip:55d203497ad4 sp:7ffeb5813e20 error:0 in php7.2[55d203156000+419000]
[169089.059688] traps: php[29152] general protection ip:55595db0a293 sp:7fff98ce30a0 error:0 in php7.2[55595d853000+419000]
[169280.116888] traps: php[29159] general protection ip:556772007ad4 sp:7ffc1c89b1d0 error:0 in php7.2[556771cc6000+419000]
[169282.114056] traps: php[29161] general protection ip:55ed3ab32be0 sp:7ffca8c53820 error:0 in php7.2[55ed3a8b8000+419000]
[169283.565760] traps: php[29163] general protection ip:55edd7b73ad4 sp:7ffd23dc6a10 error:0 in php7.2[55edd7832000+419000]
[169288.703892] traps: php[29165] general protection ip:558527bc5ad4 sp:7fff41e888a0 error:0 in php7.2[558527884000+419000]
[169331.512869] traps: php[29170] general protection ip:563e00ddfad4 sp:7ffd503eada0 error:0 in php7.2[563e00a9e000+419000]
[169408.724444] traps: php[29187] general protection ip:561e2ed6cbe0 sp:7ffeab26dd00 error:0 in php7.2[561e2eaf2000+419000]
[169462.063710] traps: php[29200] general protection ip:561682a69ad4 sp:7ffe4634d730 error:0 in php7.2[561682728000+419000]
```

if I remove code `statement = $db->insert(...` seems all works.

Any idea what need to do to fix problem?

Update:

`gdb` return this information:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005555557cebe0 in _emalloc ()
#1  0x00005555557f9d52 in add_assoc_string_ex ()
#2  0x00007ffff254be55 in ?? () from /usr/lib/php/20170718/curl.so
#3  0x00005555558a6a6b in execute_ex ()
#4  0x00005555557e67de in zend_call_function ()
#5  0x00005555557e6c95 in _call_user_function_ex ()
#6  0x00007fffec8aa407 in ?? () from /usr/lib/php/20170718/gearman.so
#7  0x00007fffec680a87 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgearman.so.8
#8  0x00007fffec689851 in gearman_worker_work () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgearman.so.8
#9  0x00007fffec8ab8cd in zif_gearman_worker_work () from /usr/lib/php/20170718/gearman.so
#10 0x00005555558a7298 in execute_ex ()
#11 0x00005555558a83a7 in zend_execute ()
#12 0x00005555557f6d92 in zend_execute_scripts ()
#13 0x00005555557921f0 in php_execute_script ()
#14 0x00005555558aa7bc in ?? ()
#15 0x00005555556405bb in ?? ()
#16 0x00007ffff5ebcb97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x5555556401a0, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe588, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, 
    stack_end=0x7fffffffe578) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#17 0x000055555564075a in _start ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS running PHP 7.2.24.
I found out that this was a bug in the gearman-php extension (which has been [fixed](https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman/issues/49)).

To remedy this you need to download, compile and install the gearman pecl module

```
cd /tmp/
sudo wget https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman/archive/gearman-2.0.6.zip
unzip gearman-2.0.6.zip
cd pecl-gearman-gearman-2.0.6
sudo phpize
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

For a complete install of gearman for PHP7 on Ubuntu, please refer to this [guide](https://techearl.com/php/installing-gearman-module-for-php7-on-ubuntu)